# Como posso avaliar o desempenho em uma aplicação .net core em f#

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, f#, profiling

Eu gostaria de fazer profile á minha aplicação `asp.net-core` desenvolvida em `f#`. Não consegui utilizar o profiler incluido no visual studio para esse efeito.

Como posso avaliar o desempenho da minha aplicação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A informação de desempenho da aplicação é disponibilizada na janela de diagnóstico.
Nessa janela também é possível habilitar o profiling da aplição, para ter mais detalhes de quais os métodos estão a consumir mais recursos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]